# How to determine if a Couchbase View exists in a bucket? (.NET api)

Tags: c#, .net, nosql, couchbase

Currently you can find out that a view doesn't exists when you try to perform a query after attempting to retrieve the view:

```
var result = _couchClient.GetView<etc>("DocumentName", "ViewNameThatDoesNotExist");
result.Count(); // This returns a service exception
```

You find out it doesn't exist after Count throws an exception, so at the moment I use a try/catch to determine if there is an exception.

Is there a more elegant solution that doesn't require as many resources as performing a query?
There doesn't seem to be anything like

```
result.exists()
```

or something similar.

Comment: To clarify, executing the command:

`var result = _couchClient.GetView<etc>("DocumentName", "ViewNameThatDoesNotExist");`

will not raise an exception even if the view does not exist, and result will not be null. There will only be an exception when a query is performed on the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matt - thanks for sharing your extension method!  Having seen this question pop up a couple of times now, I'm baking support into the 1.2.1 client (to be released on Feb 05, 2013).   The answer that follows isn't valid in 1.2.0, but is a preview for future reference.  I'm also including it as an answer instead of a comment for better code highlighting...

In 1.2.1, there will be two ways to check for a view not existing.  The first is to use the view's new CheckExists() method.  This method will query the design document and parse the JSON.  Similar to Matt's approach, but doesn't use the CouchbaseCluster API.

```
var view = client.GetView("designDoc", "viewName")

if (view.CheckExists())
{
  view.Count();
}
```

The second approach is to catch the exception, which is meaningfully typed (no longer an InvalidOperationException). The advantage of this approach is one fewer HTTP query.

```
var view = client.GetView("designDoc", "viewName")

try {
    view.Count();
} catch (ViewNotFoundException vnfe) { //extends ViewException
    ...
} catch (ViewException ve) { //bad params for example
   log.Error("Error {0}, Reason {1}", ve.Error, ve.Reason);
} catch (Exception e) {
   ...
}
```

The Jira request is at http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/NCBC-165 and the code is in review at http://review.couchbase.org/#/c/24068/1.

Comment: Happy to help!  That's the beauty of open source.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I have created an overloaded CouchbaseClient that solve this problem. It's fast and works pretty well.

Edit: I did a small change, I'm not using string.contains, I use Json Objects.

```
public class CouchbaseClientExtended : CouchbaseClient
{
    private string _bucket;
    private bool _isDevMode;
    private CouchbaseCluster _cluster;

    public CouchbaseClientExtended()
    {
        LoadBaseConfig("couchbase");
    }

    public CouchbaseClientExtended(CouchbaseClientConfiguration config) : base(config)
    {
        LoadBaseConfig(config);
    }

    public CouchbaseClientExtended(string sectionName) : base(sectionName)
    {
        LoadBaseConfig(sectionName);
    }

    public CouchbaseClientExtended(ICouchbaseServerPool pool, CouchbaseClientConfiguration config) : base(pool, config)
    {
        LoadBaseConfig(config);
    }

    public CouchbaseClientExtended(string bucketName, string bucketPassword) : base(bucketName, bucketPassword)
    {
        var config = new CouchbaseClientConfiguration
        {
            Bucket = bucketName,
            BucketPassword = bucketPassword
        };
        LoadBaseConfig(config);
        _bucket = bucketName;
    }

    public CouchbaseClientExtended(CouchbaseClientConfiguration config, string bucketName, string bucketPassword) : base(config, bucketName, bucketPassword)
    {
        LoadBaseConfig(config);
        _bucket = bucketName;
    }

    public CouchbaseClientExtended(string sectionName, string bucketName, string bucketPassword)
        : base(sectionName, bucketName, bucketPassword)
    {
        LoadBaseConfig(sectionName);
        _bucket = bucketName;
    }

    private void LoadBaseConfig(string sectionName)
    {
        var config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection(sectionName) as CouchbaseClientSection;
        if (config == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException(
                "Couchbase configuration cannot be null. Add it to App.Config file or pass a custom one via parameter.");
        }
        _bucket = config.Servers.Bucket;
        _isDevMode = config.DocumentNameTransformer.Type == typeof (DevelopmentModeNameTransformer);
        _cluster = new CouchbaseCluster(config);
    }

    private void LoadBaseConfig(CouchbaseClientConfiguration config)
    {
        _bucket = config.Bucket;
        _isDevMode = config.DesignDocumentNameTransformer is DevelopmentModeNameTransformer;
        _cluster = new CouchbaseCluster(config);
    }

    public bool StoreJson<T>(StoreMode storeMode, string key, T value) where T : class
    {
        return Store(storeMode, key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public T GetJson<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
        T obj = null;
        var json = Get<string>(key);
        if (json != null)
        {
            obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }
        return obj;
    }

    public bool ViewExist(string designName, string viewName)
    {
        try
        {
            var doc = _cluster.RetrieveDesignDocument(_bucket, designName);
            if (!VerifyDesignDocumentContainsView(doc, viewName))
            {
                if (_isDevMode)
                {
                    var devDoc = _cluster.RetrieveDesignDocument(_bucket, "dev_" + designName);
                    return VerifyDesignDocumentContainsView(devDoc, viewName);
                }
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            if (((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                return false;
            }
            throw;
        }
    }

    private bool VerifyDesignDocumentContainsView(string doc, string viewName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(doc) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        {
            return false;
        }

        JToken token;
        JObject jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(doc);
        jObject.TryGetValue("views", out token);
        if (token != null)
        {
            jObject = (JObject)token;
            return jObject.TryGetValue(viewName, out token);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope it works well for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the Design REST API, not sure it is more elegant, see
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-views-designdoc-api-retrieving.html

This approach is a very generic approach.

I am not .Net expert but in the Java SDK when you are calling the getView() method, if the view does not exit a Exception is raised. Maybe you have a similar way in .Net

Comment: The REST API is an alternative, but then I lose the support of the C# API, and in the case where the view exists, it is very helpful and useful in performing my queries.
Unfortunately I cannot switch to Java, and again the .Net version, when you call the GetView() method, it does not raise an exception if the view does not exist.